# XAML ListView Items IsEnabled

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, isenabled

I have the following XAML :

```
            <Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="8,8">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Setting 'UsingItems' here -->
                <CheckBox Grid.Row="0"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=UsingItems}" 
                    Content="{Binding Path=IncludeItemsText}" />

                <!-- This works as expected -->
                <CheckBox Grid.Row="1"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=UsingItems}"/>

                <!-- This doesn't! Even though the ListView becomes enabled the Items aren't and the Checkboxes are not checkable! -->
                <ListView Grid.Row="2" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=UsingItems}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SortedItems}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <CheckBox
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=.IsSelected}"
                                    Margin="0,2" Click="CheckBox_Click" />
                                <TextBlock
                                    Text="{Binding Path=.Item.ItemDescription}"
                                    Margin="4,0,0,0" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
```

I would like to Disable all Items in the ListView if the property 'UsingItems' = false. 'UsingItems' is set using the Checkbox in Row 0, I've confirmed this is working by having a dummy Checkbox in Row 1 - the 'IsEnabled' property is set as expected.

However, the ListView Items remain disabled when 'UsingItems' = true, even though the ListView becomes enabled (and the items 'look' enabled).

I had assumed the IsEnabled property would filter down the tree - but this is not happening here.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: Have you implemented `INPC` on your ViewModel class and raise `PropertyChanged` event on its setter?

Comment: I tested it in small sample and it works fine for me. ListViewItems are getting enabled alongwith ListView itself.

Comment: Thanks - are you able to Click the CheckBox inside the listViewItem?

Comment: Yeah i am able to click. `Binding` seems incorrect to me for inner checkbox - `IsChecked="{Binding Path=.IsSelected}"`

Comment: Thanks, When I save the Item, exit the form then Re-edit, the ListViewItems are editable as expected.. must be something wrong with my intialization, haven't figured it out :-/

Comment: Strange.. Is Xaml same as above?